# Which controller variable should have the current action name: action or actionName?

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 2.1.0 and have a save() action on a controller, with two parameters:

def save(String templateId, String action)

When I submit a form with a field called "action" with the vaule "xxxx", and I println action, I get "save".

The doc says that the current action name should be on the actionName variable **, but it seems Grails is also putting the action name on my "action" variable.

Anyone knows why is that happening? Is it a bug or an expected behavior?

** http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.1.0/ref/Controllers/actionName.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's from `UrlMappings.groovy`. The named variables in mapping config lines become variables in the `params` map, so this default mapping

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
    ...
}
```

will create a `controller` variable, and if there's an action specified it will be in the `action` variable, and if there's an id, `id`. The same goes for any variables you specify yourself, e.g.

```
"/api/v1.0/publish/$plugin/$version"(controller:"repository", action:"publish")
```

defines `plugin` and `version` variables.